# Performance in string comparison

Tags: java, performance

I am checking the performance of the code, I have `"".equals(string)` in java string value comparison but i have got information like `string.trim().length() == 0` gives better performance. Is it true?
I have got doubt about this because `"".equals(string)` will take care even if string is null but for the second thing first we need to null check then only we can trim the string.

which one is better to use: `if("".equals(string))`  or `if(string.trim().length() == 0)`.

Comment: these 2 are different

Comment: how those can be different?

Comment: one trims the string, one does not. One returns true for `"   "`, the other returns false.

Comment: Please look into edited question, in both the cases true or false will be return

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" - Donald Knuth

Comment: Its not our own optimization, its a report generated by tool.

Answer (score 4):

`string.trim().length() == 0` is not the same result as `"".equals(string)`. There is no sense in comparing their performance because they serve different purposes. (However, for the purpose of speculation `string.trim().length() == 0` will generally be slower because [`trim`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--) involves an array copy.)

- `string.trim().length() == 0` means "string might not be empty but only contains whitespace".
- `"".equals(string)` means "string is only empty or null".

Just for example `"".equals(" ")` evaluates to false but `" ".trim().length() == 0` evaluates to true.

Now the results of the expressions `"".equals(string)` and `string != null && string.length() == 0` are the same. `string != null && string.length() == 0` will *technically* be faster but it really doesn't matter. The difference will be so small, on the scale of a few nanoseconds. This is because `"".equals(string)` will only get as far as comparing the lengths.

Also in general this is not the type of thing to worry about optimizing.

Comment: @majji One is simply not better than another. These expressions have different meanings. If you don't want to throw a NPE you can just as soon as do `string != null && string.trim().length() == 0` *but this has different meaning* from `"".equals(string)`.

Comment: Thank you @Radiodef, that's a tool report,here we have to follow the suugestions given by tool. So the tool is asking to change from "".equals(string) to string.trim().length() == 0. but it is not considering null check while calculating the performance.  for saftey purpose we are adding a null check without tool suggestion

Comment: You should really ignore this tool's suggestion unless it can explain to you why changing the semantics of your code is acceptable as a substitution.

Comment: FWIW, instead of `.length() == 0`, I'd use `.isEmpty()` (available since JDK6).

Answer (score 0):

This both approaches are different
approach 1:
`if("".equals(string))` - compare your strings it return true if both string having same contents. 
[refer java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

> boolean   equals(Object anObject)
>   Compares this string to the specified object.

and

approach 2 :

`if(string.trim().length() == 0)`  - compare length of string, if both string having same length then it will return true.

To handle null prointer exception, you have to first check whether string is null or not in second approach then call `trim()` method on string object.

Comment: "To handle null prointer exception, you have to first check whether string is null or not in second approach then call trim() method on string object." So what if string is null,which one is better?

Comment: approach 1 is better approach if the string is null. it will not through null pointer exception.